# How to store messages sent by specific user in discordjs?

Tags: javascript, foreach, discord, bots

I'm trying to create a discord js bot which can send a random message by a specified user.
Here's my attept:

```
const ch = client.channels.cache.get("12345");
const soma = client.users.cache.get("4321");
if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+'test')){
    console.log(`${ch}`);
    ch.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then(messages => {
        console.log(`Received ${messages.size} messages`);
        messages.forEach(message => message.author.id)
        messages.forEach(function (message){
            if (message.author.id === {soma}){
                console.log(message.content);
            }
        })
    })
};
```

I just can't figure out how to put the author id and the message content into an array or just go thru it when the command is executed.

Comment: No, I have asked it in a different way in a new post.

Answer (score -1):

Ok i read ur script and at the `const soma = client.users.cache.get("4321");` part i noticed that ur trying to get the id from the users of the bot which isnot needed u can just use the id instantly so all u ahve to do is making soma defined as ur id no need for client.cache.get just like this `const soma = "332036461669122048"` for example, and for the channel you can just make it into `const ch = message.channel.id` instead of getting the channel from the client cuz ur getting it in a wrong way

Edit: and at the `if (message.author.id === {soma})` you dont need to add the "{","}" its not needed